# Correct way of defining NULL and NULL_POINTER?

Tags: c, pointers, null, c-preprocessor

As far as I know, **C** defines `NULL` like this:

```
#define NULL ( (void *) 0)
```

Then, how should we define `NULL_POINTER` ? I defined it the same in my program and it worked, but I suppose that is just a coincidence:

```
#define NULL_POINTER ( (void *) 0)
```

What would be the logical definition, if any ?

Comment: `NULL` **is** a null pointer, why do you want a separate define for that?

Comment: You should leave the definition for the implementation. Defining your own version of NULL can only make things worse.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
#define NULL ( (void *) 0)
```

and

```
#define NULL 0
```

are both valid. If you need to implement your own macro for null pointer, the same rule applies.

> ### C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §6.3.2.3 *Pointers* Section 3
>
> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type
> `void *`, is called a null pointer constant

Comment: @PaulR According to http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.2.3, it's the same in C99. Although I do agree that the first definition is better.

Comment: The first definition seems better to me since in some compilers comparing a numeric value to NULL results in a warning (e.g. _"[Warning] comparison between pointer and integer"_) while the second definition doesn't. Thus, the first definition provides better semantics.

Answer (score 5):

It is only in pointer contexts that `NULL` and `0` are equivalent. `NULL` should not be used when another kind of `0` is required, even though it might work, because doing so sends the wrong stylistic message. (Furthermore, ANSI allows the definition of `NULL` to be `((void *)0)`, which will not work at all in non-pointer contexts.) In particular, do not use `NULL` when the ASCII null character (NUL) is desired. Provide your own definition

```
#define NUL '\0'
```

`NULL` should be used only as a pointer constant.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is referencing the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/null/nullor0.html).