# where is __DARWIN_NULL macro definition?

Tags: c

I have to return nul in a function but I'm not allowed to include any library. I tried to find in  how is NULL defined, then to sys/_types/_null.h only to find that NULL is actually __DARWIN_NULL. Great ! Now, I have no idea where to search in order to find the __DARWIN_NULL definition...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781514/correct-way-of-defining-null-and-null-pointer

Comment: AFAIK, `__DARWIN_NULL` is a compiler built-in, so you won't find it in any header file.

Comment: Unclear whether you want the `nul` char or the `NULL` pointer. Whichever you can `return 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have to return nul in a function but I'm not allowed to include any library.

The solution to this problem is far simpler than you're making it; you've actually asked a form of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You won't find the NUL character defined in any standard library; the best way to return that will be using the constant `'\0'` or `0`.

If your professor is teaching you to avoid using `<stddef.h>` to find `NULL` then he/she has set a silly exercise which involves using something other than the most appropriate tool for the job, a tool which is guaranteed by the standard to exist, by the way... I would be raising this as a concern.

Nonetheless, sometimes professors don't care and will teach you to do stupid things anyway. `NULL` is defined as an implementation-defined null pointer constant, usually `0` or a conversion of `0` to `void *` like so: `((void *) 0)`. That may not be the implementation-defined value your `NULL` resolves to; in that case, adjust to suit :)

You could add a preprocessor definition such as `#define NULL ((void *) 0)` and then you would be able to `return NULL;` from your functions. Ta-da! Stupid exercises deserve stupid solutions.

If your professor says you're not allowed to use `#define`, either, I would be tempted to ask him what you *are* allowed to use. Changing requirements on the fly is not fair. Most compilers will allow you to set preprocessor constants using a command line argument, for example `cc -DNULL='((void *) 0)' ...`. This is useful for exposing compile-time configuration options, but again, using this to define `NULL` is dumb.

---

The question in your title is different to the rest of your post. `__DARWIN_NULL` could also be defined using either of the above, providing it isn't already defined, but I really don't think that's required to answer your actual question.