# Why am I getting this output in C++? Explain the logic

Tags: c++, if-statement, output, control-flow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
  if(NULL)
    std::cout<<"hello";
  else
    std::cout<<"world";
  return 0;
}
```

The output to the above question is:

world

Kindly explain me why am I getting this output. I am not able to get the satisfactory answer even after referring to several different sources.

Comment: NULL == 0 == false (for a given definition of ==). Therefore the if statement becomes `if(false)` etc

Comment: I am learning C++, and I read somewhere that NULL and 0 are different. So, I am a bit confused.

Comment: Have a read of:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL

Comment: [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)

Comment: *I read somewhere that NULL and 0 are different*. Don't read anything from that place. The language requires NULL and 0 to be identical.

Comment: I can't imagine any language where NULL is a "truthy" value.

Comment: *I read somewhere that NULL and 0 are different.* - Conceptually, they are different. That is, you should not, for example, use `NULL` for numeric computations. But technically, when evaluated in a context where it is interpreted as a number `NULL` will always yield the value `0` (at least before C++11).

Comment: gotcha! @ComicSansMS

Comment: @PalakJain you might have confused `NULL` and `nullptr`. `nullptr` is the one that has a separate type, but even that will be implicitly converted to a type that will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` results in a false condition. You could imagine that `NULL` is a 0, so this:

```
if(NULL)
```

would be equivalent to this:

```
if(0)
```

thus your code would become:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
  if(0)
    std::cout<<"hello";
  else
    std::cout<<"world";
  return 0;
}
```

where is obvious that because 0 results to false, the if condition is not satisfied, thus the body of the if-statement is not executed. As a result, the body of the else-statement is executed, which explains the output you see.

---

PS: [Correct way of defining NULL and NULL_POINTER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781514/correct-way-of-defining-null-and-null-pointer)