# index shows NULL inside for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, null, malloc

I want to multiply matrixes. I create matrix by `malloc()` function. Index (variable named `i`) shows `NULL`, instead of number

```
int** matrix_a = (int**)malloc(lines * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    if (i == NULL) 
        printf("'i' is NULL!");
    matrix_a[i] = (int*)malloc(trans * sizeof(int*));
}
```

**Output:**

> 'i' is NULL!

**Error:**

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6003C35BB in MPI_C.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFFABA57A00.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with `i == NULL`?

Comment: Clean language would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc()`.

Comment: `NULL` could be something like `0` which is the initial value of `i`. Read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_null.htm

Comment: NULL is zero... not magical like in some higher level languages.

Comment: @J...S That site looks crappy. Those are not the only possible values of `NULL`, so why mention `0L` specifically? (The C standard also allows `(42 - 42)`, `(1 / sizeof "A")`, etc.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18781550/5375464 Any integer constant expression with the value `0` or such an expression cast to type `(void *)`.

Comment: Use effective 2D matrices instead of pointer-to-pointer pseudo matrices.

Comment: Just curious why all the down votes on this? The user stated what they want to accomplish and provided what they tried. I am not very familiar with C so maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to compare non-pointers to `NULL`. The `NULL` macro expands to an integer constant `0`, possibly cast to `(void *)`.

In the former case, your code just checks `if (i == 0)`, which is true in the first iteration of the loop. In the latter case, you're doing `if (i == ((void *)0))`, which your compiler should be complaining about because it's a type error.

Only use `NULL` for pointer values, not numbers.